# How to install Citrix receiver xubuntu 13.04 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, xubuntu, citrix

Anyone have a walkthrough on installing Citrix receiver on Xubuntu 13.04 64-bit?

---

**Update**

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmotif4 nspluginwrapper

 ... snip ... 
Setting up libmotif4:amd64 (2.3.3-7ubuntu1) ... 
Setting up nspluginviewer (1.4.4-0ubuntu5) ... 
Setting up nspluginwrapper (1.4.4-0ubuntu5) ... 
plugin dirs: nspluginwrapper: no appropriate viewer found for /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so 
Auto-update plugins from /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins 
Looking for plugins in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins 
Segmentation fault (core dumped) Processing triggers for libc-bin ... 
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place 

sudo dpkg --install Downloads/icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package icaclient. 
(Reading database ... 155808 files and directories currently installed.) 
Unpacking icaclient (from .../icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb) ... 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icaclient: 
icaclient depends on libc6-i386 (>= 2.7-1); 
however: Package libc6-i386 is not installed. icaclient depends on ia32-libs; 
however: Package ia32-libs is not installed. 
icaclient depends on lib32z1; 
however: Package lib32z1 is not installed. icaclient depends on lib32asound2; 
however: Package lib32asound2 is not installed. dpkg: 
error processing icaclient (--install): dependency problems - 
leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing: icaclient
```

Comment: Take a look at [Citrix ICA Client How To](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo).

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install libmotif4 nspluginwrapper
... snip ...
Setting up libmotif4:amd64 (2.3.3-7ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nspluginviewer (1.4.4-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up nspluginwrapper (1.4.4-0ubuntu5) ...
plugin dirs:
nspluginwrapper: no appropriate viewer found for /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
Auto-update plugins from /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
Looking for plugins in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
$

(puny 29 chars left. see next comment)

Comment: Tried to continue in spite of error above:

sudo dpkg --install Downloads/icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package icaclient.
(Reading database ... 155808 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking icaclient (from .../icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icaclient:
 icaclient depends on libc6-i386 (>= 2.7-1); however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 icaclient depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.

<continued in next comment>

Comment: icaclient depends on lib32z1; however:
  Package lib32z1 is not installed.
 icaclient depends on lib32asound2; however:
  Package lib32asound2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing icaclient (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient
$

Comment: See if [this](http://techcell.chaseorigina.l.com/technotes/install-citrix-receiver-on-64bit-ubuntu/) helps you

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.  Open a terminal and enter:  **sudo apt-get install libmotif4 nspluginwrapper**

Step 2.  Download and install the receiver. See the following video to understand what to download and what to expect when installing the receiver:  **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZVxNH76kj0**
(Link to the official Citrix Receiver 12.1 .deb:  https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/receivers-by-platform/receiver-for-linux-121.html)

Step 3.  When complete copy the certificates to the proper directory:
**sudo cp /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts**

Step 4.  When accessing the Citrix environment tell the browser to open launch.ica (or launch.jsp) by using the following as the default app:  **/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/wfica.sh**

Good luck!